# Solr search based on stemming

Tags: solr, schema, solrconfig

I have a scenario where I have used SnowballPorterFilterFactory to stem that field.

Now it stores all talent types like ex: Actor, Dancer, Singer, Model, etc.

This stemming helps me to search using

```
Actor in mumbai
```

AND

```
Actors in mumbai
```

Both.

Now I want to search with

```
show all who sings in mumbai
```

How can I match **sing** with **singer** ??

It does not matching for now ..

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Analysis" page of the Solr admin interface to see what stemming is being performed for `singer`. This allows you to see each step for both terms, and what the end result for both `sing` and `singer` is.

The difference is probably casued by the fact that they're not actually the same word - singer is a subject, while sing is a verb, and stemming them to the same word might give bad results. You may get better results by using a synonym word list in this case. The correct stemming of `singer` is probably just `singer` (singer, singers).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have solved this issue by creating my own field type **text_stemming**, in which I have used 2 filter factories. **solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory** and **solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory**. Now snowball will be used for stemming like **singers** => **singer** and EdgeNGramFilterFactory will help me for partial search. Thanks